# Priority Queue - Explanation

Tags: data-structures, queue, priority-queue

as far as I know, a priority queue is a type of queue that arranges elements based on their priority values. Elements with higher priority values are typically retrieved before elements with lower priority values.

[image: The Slide]

But here in this slide, he says that if x has a lower priority than y, x will be deleted first!

Here I am confused as the definition states that the priority queue with the highest priority value is retrieved first, I was wondering what's wrong ?!, how can I link these ideas together, please clarify

Comment: Hi! I'm struggling to understand your question.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, or links to images of text. You should [edit] your question to include the relevant information you're asking about.

Comment: @pjs - Thanks I change it

Comment: The “highest priority” can be either the the largest value or the smallest value in the set, so priority queues can be organized as max-priority or min-priority access. The slide describes a min-priority queue. It sounds like you’ve interpreted “highest priority” as always being largest value. It’s the difference between “We’re in first place!” vs “Who has the highest score?” Either description could be the winning team .

Comment: Note that the slide says “lower priority ***value***”, not “lower priority”.

Comment: The important thing is that they come out in sorted order.  Whether that means ascending or descending order doesn't really matter -- it's still a priority queue.